# Getting IllegalAccessError for com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.FilteredBeanPropertyWriter on release build only

Tags: android, jodatime, jackson-databind

This crash happens only in release build, works fine in debug build. It happens on app startup when all dependencies are injected.

```
 @JvmStatic
 @Provides
 internal fun provideJackson() = ObjectMapper()
           .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
            .registerModule(JodaModule())
            .disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
```

I am using jacksonVersion 2.9.5

```
// Jackson
'jacksonCore'         : "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:${versions.jacksonVersion}",
'jacksonAnnotations'  : "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:${versions.jacksonVersion}",
'jacksonDatabind'     : "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:${versions.jacksonVersion}",
'jacksonDataTypeJoda' : "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda:${versions.jacksonVersion}",
```

I tried updating jackson to 2.9.9, didn't work.

This is the crash that I am getting

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class l.c.a.e.n$c[] from class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.FilteredBeanPropertyWriter
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.FilteredBeanPropertyWriter.b(FilteredBeanPropertyWriter.java:34)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.cfg.FormatConfig.<clinit>(FormatConfig.java:22)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.deser.DateTimeDeserializer.forType(DateTimeDeserializer.java:1)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.JodaModule.<init>(JodaModule.java:2)
        at c.f.d.a.d.e.a(CatcherModule.kt:4)
```

The de-obfuscated stack trace looks like this

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class l.c.a.e.n$c[] from class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.FilteredBeanPropertyWriter
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.FilteredBeanPropertyWriter.org.joda.time.format.PeriodFormatterBuilder.toFormatter(FilteredBeanPropertyWriter.java:34)
                                                                              org.joda.time.format.ISOPeriodFormat.standard
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.cfg.FormatConfig.<clinit>(FormatConfig.java:22)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.deser.DateTimeDeserializer.forType(DateTimeDeserializer.java:1)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.JodaModule.<init>(JodaModule.java:2)
```

Answer (score 0):

`-keepclassmembers class org.joda.time.format.** { *; }` solved my issue